# How do I find out the current page number of a determined word in Microsoft word using vba macro (or python)

Tags: python, vba, ms-word

I have the daunting task of correcting the page numbers of a book's index that was translated, and thus had the references of the occurrences of each item on that index pointed to the wrong page number.

So basically I want to make a VBA macro to search for each term in the index of the book, then find out which are the page numbers where they occur in and finally update the index.

What I was wondering is two things:

1. Do you think using VBA for this is a good option or is it time-consuming? And if you feel it isn't a bad idea, how do I get the page number of a determined word?
2. Are there any other, better ways of achieving the same result using, perhaps, Python, which I'm more comfortable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of "pages" in a document would vary greatly, depending on font size, paper size, line-spacing, margins, etc. etc. etc.  so attempting this in Word is unreliable at best. Proceed with that in mind, please.

Refer to [this explanation](http://shaunakelly.com/word/word-development/selecting-or-referring-to-a-page-in-the-word-object-model.html) and ensuing commentary:

> Q. I'd like to cycle through all the pages in my Word document and  on each page. How do I do this?
>
> A. You can't.  Word is not page layout software. It's a word processor. It sees text as a scroll. Each document is one long scroll of text.

One hack that you might use in conjunction with the `Find` method, subject to the caveat about reliability of course:

```vb
Sub findpage()
Dim p As Long 'page number
Dim rngFound As Find
Dim searchText As String

searchText = "some text you want to find"

Set rngFound = ActiveDocument.Range.Find
    rngFound.Text = searchText
    rngFound.Execute
    
    If rngFound.Found Then
        p = rngFound.Parent.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
    
    Else
        'not found
    End If
    
    MsgBox searchText & " found on page " & p

End Sub
```

Practically speaking you will have to tweak this for your purposes, I am only showing you the **method** you can use to arrive at the page number for a particular search term within a document.

The choice of VBA or Python (or some TBD language) is yours and yours alone to make.